# MongoDB config for Spring Boot - 'url' with and without authentication credentials

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I want to make the *application.yml* work with and without username/password when running tests. My server needs the credentials but when I am on localhost I want it to work without an authentication and with the default settings. The spring profile ("*integrationtest*") should stay the same.

I have the following Spring Boot MongoDB config:

```
mongodb:
  uri: mongodb://${mongodb_username:testuser}:${mongodb_password:testpassword}@${mongodb_ip:localhost}:${mongodb_port:27017}/testDB
```

If I remove the username and password I get this Error:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='testuser', source='testDB', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='testuser', source='testDB', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}
```

How can I make it work with the same profile? Maybe there is a way with nested variables? Thank you.

Comment: I could put the full uri inside a variable

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to put the complete uri in a single variable, localhost works with the default config and the server specifies the uri at server start. The config looks like:

```
  uri: ${mongodb_uri:mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB}
```

At server start override it with:

```
-Dmongodb_uri=mongodb://testUser:testPassword@example.com:27017/testDB
```